# In my database - Error 1062 Dublicate entry key PRIMARY

Tags: mysql, database

I create my database about school, when i run project MySQQL view Error 1062 Dublicate entry key PRIMARY. How can I fix the error?
[image]

-- MySQL dump 10.13  Distrib 8.0.12, for Win64 (x86_64)
    --
    -- Host: localhost    Database: school_db_newnew
    -- ------------------------------------------------------
    -- Server version   8.0.12

```
/*!40101 SET @OLD_CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT=@@CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT */;
/*!40101 SET @OLD_CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS=@@CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS */;
/*!40101 SET @OLD_COLLATION_CONNECTION=@@COLLATION_CONNECTION */;
 SET NAMES utf8 ;
/*!40103 SET @OLD_TIME_ZONE=@@TIME_ZONE */;
/*!40103 SET TIME_ZONE='+00:00' */;
/*!40014 SET @OLD_UNIQUE_CHECKS=@@UNIQUE_CHECKS, UNIQUE_CHECKS=0 */;
/*!40014 SET @OLD_FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=@@FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS, FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=0 */;
/*!40101 SET @OLD_SQL_MODE=@@SQL_MODE, SQL_MODE='NO_AUTO_VALUE_ON_ZERO' */;
/*!40111 SET @OLD_SQL_NOTES=@@SQL_NOTES, SQL_NOTES=0 */;

--
-- Dumping data for table `class`
--

LOCK TABLES `class` WRITE;
/*!40000 ALTER TABLE `class` DISABLE KEYS */;
INSERT INTO `class` VALUES (111,'1A'),(112,'1B'),(113,'1C'),(114,'2A'),(115,'2B'),(116,'3A'),(117,'3B');
/*!40000 ALTER TABLE `class` ENABLE KEYS */;
UNLOCK TABLES;

--
-- Dumping data for table `class_subject_connection`
--

LOCK TABLES `class_subject_connection` WRITE;
/*!40000 ALTER TABLE `class_subject_connection` DISABLE KEYS */;
INSERT INTO `class_subject_connection` VALUES (1,111,29),(2,111,24),(3,111,28),(4,116,29),(5,116,12),(6,115,14),(7,114,15),(8,113,17),(9,114,17),(10,115,18),(11,113,20),(12,115,23),(13,112,21),(14,116,22);
/*!40000 ALTER TABLE `class_subject_connection` ENABLE KEYS */;
UNLOCK TABLES;

--
-- Dumping data for table `grade`
--

LOCK TABLES `grade` WRITE;
/*!40000 ALTER TABLE `grade` DISABLE KEYS */;
/*!40000 ALTER TABLE `grade` ENABLE KEYS */;
UNLOCK TABLES;

--
-- Dumping data for table `grade_value`
--

LOCK TABLES `grade_value` WRITE;
/*!40000 ALTER TABLE `grade_value` DISABLE KEYS */;
INSERT INTO `grade_value` VALUES (1,1),(2,2),(3,3),(4,4),(5,5);
/*!40000 ALTER TABLE `grade_value` ENABLE KEYS */;
UNLOCK TABLES;

--
-- Dumping data for table `hibernate_sequence`
--

LOCK TABLES `hibernate_sequence` WRITE;
/*!40000 ALTER TABLE `hibernate_sequence` DISABLE KEYS */;
INSERT INTO `hibernate_sequence` VALUES (107);
/*!40000 ALTER TABLE `hibernate_sequence` ENABLE KEYS */;
UNLOCK TABLES;

--
-- Dumping data for table `student`
--

LOCK TABLES `student` WRITE;
/*!40000 ALTER TABLE `student` DISABLE KEYS */;
INSERT INTO `student` VALUES (100,NULL,'bez','photo',NULL),(101,NULL,'User','12343',NULL),(102,NULL,'admin1','','avatar1371003006780604505.i0d');
/*!40000 ALTER TABLE `student` ENABLE KEYS */;
UNLOCK TABLES;

--
-- Dumping data for table `students`
--

LOCK TABLES `students` WRITE;
/*!40000 ALTER TABLE `students` DISABLE KEYS */;
INSERT INTO `students` VALUES (1,'1','1'),(2,'Mac','Windows');
/*!40000 ALTER TABLE `students` ENABLE KEYS */;
UNLOCK TABLES;

--
-- Dumping data for table `subject`
--

LOCK TABLES `subject` WRITE;
/*!40000 ALTER TABLE `subject` DISABLE KEYS */;
INSERT INTO `subject` VALUES (11,'Algebra'),(12,'Geometry'),(13,'Chemistry'),(14,'Informatix'),(15,'History'),(16,'Biology'),(17,'English'),(18,'Physics'),(19,'Physical Culture'),(20,'Labour Lesson'),(21,'Art'),(22,'Literature'),(23,'Music'),(24,'Social studies'),(25,'Science'),(26,'Psychology'),(27,'Reading'),(28,'Health'),(29,'Geography'),(30,'Mathematics');
/*!40000 ALTER TABLE `subject` ENABLE KEYS */;
UNLOCK TABLES;

--
-- Dumping data for table `teacher`
--

LOCK TABLES `teacher` WRITE;
/*!40000 ALTER TABLE `teacher` DISABLE KEYS */;
INSERT INTO `teacher` VALUES (810111,'Steve Jobs'),(810112,'Bill Gates'),(810113,'Ilon Mask'),(810114,'Tony Stark'),(810115,'Army Hammer'),(810116,'Bruce Banner'),(810117,'Bruce Wayne'),(810118,'Peter Parker'),(810119,'Rid Richards');
/*!40000 ALTER TABLE `teacher` ENABLE KEYS */;
UNLOCK TABLES;

--
-- Dumping data for table `teacher_subject_connection`
--

LOCK TABLES `teacher_subject_connection` WRITE;
/*!40000 ALTER TABLE `teacher_subject_connection` DISABLE KEYS */;
INSERT INTO `teacher_subject_connection` VALUES (1,11,810115),(2,15,810112),(3,12,810116),(4,17,810117),(5,16,810113),(6,21,810118),(7,28,810119),(8,29,810111),(9,18,810114),(10,13,810111),(11,14,810118),(12,19,810115),(13,22,810113),(14,23,810111),(15,24,810119),(16,25,810114),(17,26,810112),(18,27,810118),(19,30,810115),(20,20,810117),(21,29,810116);
/*!40000 ALTER TABLE `teacher_subject_connection` ENABLE KEYS */;
UNLOCK TABLES;

--
-- Dumping data for table `users`
--

LOCK TABLES `users` WRITE;
/*!40000 ALTER TABLE `users` DISABLE KEYS */;
INSERT INTO `users` VALUES (101,'a','123','ROLE_ADMIN'),(102,'t','123','ROLE_USER'),(103,'Victor_new','123','ROLE_USER'),(104,'test','test','ADMIN_ROLE'),(105,'test2','test2','ADMIN_ROLE'),(106,'1','123','USER_ADMIN');
/*!40000 ALTER TABLE `users` ENABLE KEYS */;
UNLOCK TABLES;
/*!40103 SET TIME_ZONE=@OLD_TIME_ZONE */;

/*!40101 SET SQL_MODE=@OLD_SQL_MODE */;
/*!40014 SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=@OLD_FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS */;
/*!40014 SET UNIQUE_CHECKS=@OLD_UNIQUE_CHECKS */;
/*!40101 SET CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT=@OLD_CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT */;
/*!40101 SET CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS=@OLD_CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS */;
/*!40101 SET COLLATION_CONNECTION=@OLD_COLLATION_CONNECTION */;
/*!40111 SET SQL_NOTES=@OLD_SQL_NOTES */;

-- Dump completed on 2019-08-14 19:40:21
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A primary column can only store one unique data entry. If you attempt to insert an existing data into the column again, you will receive the error message Duplicate entry on PRIMARY. Therefore, you can consider the following:

1. Check in your table whether this `111` value already exists or not by a simple query like:

```
    SELECT * FROM table WHERE column='111';
```

2. If you're trying to insert other data than the one already exists in the table, use `INSERT IGNORE` in your query instead.
3. If you're trying to update other column value for `111`, consider using:

```
    UPDATE table SET column1=xxx, column2=xxx WHERE column='111';
```

4. Otherwise if you're not familiar with `UPDATE` query, you can `DELETE` the data first then perform `INSERT` again:

   > A good practice before performing `DELETE` is to do `SELECT` first so you can see what is/are the data that you're deleting.

```
    SELECT * FROM table WHERE column='111';
```

Once you've seen and sure about the data you want to delete then you only change the `SELECT *` part to `DELETE` like below:

```
    DELETE FROM table WHERE column='111';
```